# create fortigate span config

Tags: firewall, mirror, fortigate

I want to create  fortigate span via GUI
source port: port 5
destination port: port 6

but show the following error message
**Please use different ports for SPAN Source and Destination.**

I create other subnet span success
how can I fix it ?
thanks